# Is there a way to use a CSS attribute selector to select a class name?

Tags: css

Is there a way to get elements with a class with a CSS attribute selector?

Something like this:

```
[class.=className]
```

Comment: from where you get `.=`? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/S%C3%A9lecteurs_d_attribut

Comment: I used `.=` in my example because the `.` matches the `.` used in class selectors (`.className`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this selector:

```
[class="className"], [class^="className "], [class$=" className"], [class*=" className "]
```

It's a bit long because we need to check whether it's just that class, whether it's at the beginning of the `class` attribute, the end, or in the middle.

Comment: Or you could just use `[class~=className]`.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax):

> ```
> [attr~=value]
> ```
>
> Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose value is a
> whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly *value*.

So this:

```
[class~=className]
```

targets all elements that has the class "className" regardless of whether is has other classes around it.

Comment: But wouldn't it get this element: `<p class="text-block">...</p>` with this selector: `class~=text` because "text-block" contains the value "text"? Or would it only select `text` if it was in a word by itself?

Comment: No, that would be how `[class*=text]` works, because it simply checks if the attribute value *contains* something. `[class~=text]` looks for "text" as one word and treats the attribute value as a *white-space separated* string of words. One of these words must be a complete match.